# unable to convert json string to POJO due to error Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, json, gson

For some reason i am not able to covert it to a POJO. The call i am making and have tried is like this:

```
NewsEntities  newsEntities = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, NewsEntities.class);
```

The mystery is that the json is not in an array. its a jsonObject i think. 
**the jsonString is [here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/nl6jh)**

The error i get in android is:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 1006 path $.results[0].org_facet
02-24 23:42:49.955 15463-15531/news.myapp.com.technewssample W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:831)
02-24 23:42:49.955 15463-15531/news.myapp.com.technewssample W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:422)
02-24 23:42:49.955 15463-15531/news.myapp.com.technewssample W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$16.read(TypeAdapters.java:410)
02-24 23:42:49.955 15463-15531/news.myapp.com.technewssample W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
02-24 23:42:49.956 15463-15531/news.myapp.com.technewssample W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(Reflect
```

the newsEntities class itself looks like this and i simply made it from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/:

```
    public class NewsEntities implements Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("copyright")
    @Expose
    private String copyright;
    @SerializedName("section")
    @Expose
    private String section;
    @SerializedName("last_updated")
    @Expose
    private String lastUpdated;
    @SerializedName("num_results")
    @Expose
    private Integer numResults;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> results = null;
    public final static Parcelable.Creator<NewsEntities> CREATOR = new Creator<NewsEntities>() {


        @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked"
        })
        public NewsEntities createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            NewsEntities instance = new NewsEntities();
            instance.status = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.copyright = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.section = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.lastUpdated = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.numResults = ((Integer) in.readValue((Integer.class.getClassLoader())));
            in.readList(instance.results, (Result.class.getClassLoader()));
            return instance;
        }

        public NewsEntities[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new NewsEntities[size]);
        }

    }
    ;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCopyright() {
        return copyright;
    }

    public void setCopyright(String copyright) {
        this.copyright = copyright;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getLastUpdated() {
        return lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(String lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Integer getNumResults() {
        return numResults;
    }

    public void setNumResults(Integer numResults) {
        this.numResults = numResults;
    }

    public List<Result> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Result> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(status);
        dest.writeValue(copyright);
        dest.writeValue(section);
        dest.writeValue(lastUpdated);
        dest.writeValue(numResults);
        dest.writeList(results);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return  0;
    }

    }
```

UPDATE: HERE IS THE RESULT CLASS:

```
    public class Result implements Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("section")
    @Expose
    private String section;
    @SerializedName("subsection")
    @Expose
    private String subsection;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("abstract")
    @Expose
    private String _abstract;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("byline")
    @Expose
    private String byline;
    @SerializedName("item_type")
    @Expose
    private String itemType;
    @SerializedName("updated_date")
    @Expose
    private String updatedDate;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    @Expose
    private String createdDate;
    @SerializedName("published_date")
    @Expose
    private String publishedDate;
    @SerializedName("material_type_facet")
    @Expose
    private String materialTypeFacet;
    @SerializedName("kicker")
    @Expose
    private String kicker;
    @SerializedName("des_facet")
    @Expose
    private List<String> desFacet = null;
    @SerializedName("org_facet")
    @Expose
    private String orgFacet;
    @SerializedName("per_facet")
    @Expose
    private String perFacet;
    @SerializedName("geo_facet")
    @Expose
    private List<String> geoFacet = null;
    @SerializedName("multimedia")
    @Expose
    private List<Multimedium> multimedia = null;
    public final static Parcelable.Creator<Result> CREATOR = new Creator<Result>() {


        @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked"
        })
        public Result createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            Result instance = new Result();
            instance.section = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.subsection = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.title = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance._abstract = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.url = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.byline = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.itemType = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.updatedDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.createdDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.publishedDate = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.materialTypeFacet = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.kicker = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            in.readList(instance.desFacet, (java.lang.String.class.getClassLoader()));
            instance.orgFacet = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            instance.perFacet = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
            in.readList(instance.geoFacet, (java.lang.String.class.getClassLoader()));
            in.readList(instance.multimedia, (Multimedium.class.getClassLoader()));
            return instance;
        }

        public Result[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new Result[size]);
        }

    }
    ;

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getSubsection() {
        return subsection;
    }

    public void setSubsection(String subsection) {
        this.subsection = subsection;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAbstract() {
        return _abstract;
    }

    public void setAbstract(String _abstract) {
        this._abstract = _abstract;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getByline() {
        return byline;
    }

    public void setByline(String byline) {
        this.byline = byline;
    }

    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public void setItemType(String itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    public String getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(String updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(String publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }

    public String getMaterialTypeFacet() {
        return materialTypeFacet;
    }

    public void setMaterialTypeFacet(String materialTypeFacet) {
        this.materialTypeFacet = materialTypeFacet;
    }

    public String getKicker() {
        return kicker;
    }

    public void setKicker(String kicker) {
        this.kicker = kicker;
    }

    public List<String> getDesFacet() {
        return desFacet;
    }

    public void setDesFacet(List<String> desFacet) {
        this.desFacet = desFacet;
    }

    public String getOrgFacet() {
        return orgFacet;
    }

    public void setOrgFacet(String orgFacet) {
        this.orgFacet = orgFacet;
    }

    public String getPerFacet() {
        return perFacet;
    }

    public void setPerFacet(String perFacet) {
        this.perFacet = perFacet;
    }

    public List<String> getGeoFacet() {
        return geoFacet;
    }

    public void setGeoFacet(List<String> geoFacet) {
        this.geoFacet = geoFacet;
    }

    public List<Multimedium> getMultimedia() {
        return multimedia;
    }

    public void setMultimedia(List<Multimedium> multimedia) {
        this.multimedia = multimedia;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(section);
        dest.writeValue(subsection);
        dest.writeValue(title);
        dest.writeValue(_abstract);
        dest.writeValue(url);
        dest.writeValue(byline);
        dest.writeValue(itemType);
        dest.writeValue(updatedDate);
        dest.writeValue(createdDate);
        dest.writeValue(publishedDate);
        dest.writeValue(materialTypeFacet);
        dest.writeValue(kicker);
        dest.writeList(desFacet);
        dest.writeValue(orgFacet);
        dest.writeValue(perFacet);
        dest.writeList(geoFacet);
        dest.writeList(multimedia);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return  0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic POJO generators may generate wrong mappings in some cases, especially if mapped fields are polymorphic or use non-standard approaches for whatever reasons. According to the error you're getting, your mapping expects a `String` but the JSON has an array at that place. In your case, `$.results[0].org_facet` points to:

```
...,"org_facet":["Amazon.com Inc","Cravath Swaine \u0026 Moore"],...
             // ^____here
```

If you change the mapping `String orgFacet` to `List<String> orgFacet`, you'll get similar errors for another fields like `perFacet` or `multimedia` (there are some more around). Since those fields are meant to be lists and `""` is just a marker for an empty array `[]` or `null`, Gson cannot handle it itself because of such a message format. However, you can make it work with such fields writing a custom type adapter that would be applicable for all lists deserialized using a single `Gson` instance.

```java
final class ArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapter<E>
        extends TypeAdapter<List<E>> {

    private final Gson gson;
    private final Type elementType;

    private ArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapter(final Gson gson, final Type elementType) {
        this.gson = gson;
        this.elementType = elementType;
    }

    static <E> TypeAdapter<List<E>> getArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapter(final Gson gson, final Type elementType) {
        return new ArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapter<>(gson, elementType);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<E> list) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken token = in.peek(); // Peek the next token
        switch ( token ) {
        case BEGIN_ARRAY: // If it's an array begin `[`, then parse it as an array
            return parseAsArray(in);
        case STRING: // Or if it's a string, parse it in another way
            return parseAsString(in);
        default:
            throw new MalformedJsonException("Unexpected token: " + token);
        }
    }

    private List<E> parseAsArray(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
        in.beginArray(); // Consume `[` from the token stream
        while ( in.peek() != END_ARRAY ) {
            final E element = gson.fromJson(in, elementType); // Delegate downstream parsing to the Gson instance
            list.add(element);
        }
        in.endArray(); // Consume `]` from the token stream
        return list;
    }

    private List<E> parseAsString(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        in.skipValue(); // in.nextString() consumes more memory accumulating the result
        return new ArrayList<>(); // Or null -- up to you. Or even Collections.emptyList(), but Gson uses mutable lists so we do
    }

}
```

The next thing is binding the type adapter and a `Gson` instance via a type adapter factory:

```java
final class ArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory arrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapterFactory = new ArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapterFactory();

    private ArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return arrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) { // Is it an instance of java.util.List? Not that getRawType() and getType() have different purposes
            final TypeAdapter<List<Object>> typeAdapter = getArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapter(gson, getListElementType(typeToken.getType()));
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final TypeAdapter<T> castTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) typeAdapter;
            return castTypeAdapter;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Type getListElementType(final Type type) {
        return type instanceof ParameterizedType // Is it a generic type with type parameters?
                ? ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0] // If yes, then we know that java.util.List has one type paremeter only
                : Object.class; // Otherwise it's a raw list, and no element type info is provided
    }

}
```

How it's used:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getArrayOrEmptyStringTypeAdapterFactory())
        .create();
```

```java
final NewsEntities newEntities = gson.fromJson(jsonString, NewsEntities.class);
System.out.println(newEntities.results.get(0).orgFacet);
System.out.println(newEntities.results.get(0).perFacet)
```

The output:

> [Amazon.com Inc, Cravath Swaine & Moore]
>   [Bezos, Jeffrey P]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't attached your result class but it looks to me like your result class has a string field instead of an array in org_facet. But it would be easier to answer if you add your Result class.

Comment: i posted the results class for your diagnosis.